# Returning only the unique values from two columns in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Is a way to create a calculated column that reads two columns and returns only the unique values from both of those columns?

Example table:

[image]

How do I go about creating something that looks like the `New Column` from the table above?

Comment: You're going to need a persisted (not calculated) RowID value so that you can unpivot this data first.

Comment: Sorry, quite new to Spotfire so not really sure what you mean by a persisted RowID value.

Comment: You need to have a unique row identifier in your data source, not a calculated column

Answer (score 0):

@J. Doe- Here is the solution for the specific case you posted.

As suggested by @scsimon, it is better to find a way to transform your table so that you can compare individual elements in Q1 and Q2.

**Note:** Strings in columns Q1 and Q2 are read as a whole but not as individual items.
Example: 'ABC, 123' is read as one string but not as 'ABC', '123'. So, we cannot compare specific elements between two columns.

*Also, this solution works only if Q2 contains Q1.*

Add a calculated column with the below custom expression.

```
right(RXReplace([Q2],[Q1],"","g"),Len(RXReplace([Q2],[Q1],"","g")) - 2)
```

**Here is the output table:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to work for some cases but not all as you mentioned. For example, I have instances where Q1 contains something like (ABC, 123) and Q2 contains (ABC) and in this case I would want the "New Column" to contain just (ABC). I should have elaborated on that instance in my original post. I'll look into what was suggested by scsimon.

Comment: @J.Doe- Could you please post all the possible scenarios in your table?

Comment: @J.Doe- Quick question - In your comment above, if Q1 contains "ABC, 123" and Q2 contains "ABC", then the unique value should be "123" but not "ABC" as per your initial request? Could you please elaborate this scenario?